# Center box when i have only one CSS

Tags: css, grid

Im working on a css based only on divs , getting the info from a while php cicle 
I have the following case, in a grid im showing the boxes like this:

```
X X X
 X X X
 X (in case if there is 7)
```

But, i need to center the 7th row in the following way:

```
 X X X
 X X X
   X
```

Please note the 7th box is in the middle, and if there is only 2, should be:

```
X X X
 X X X
  X X
```

I cant get this to work, this is my css:

```
.block .the-content {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-top: 62px;
}
```

Not sure if there is some special class for this.

Comment: replace float with inline-block then simply add `text-align:center`

Comment: good trick, this one also works,     display: inline-grid; its ok to use this? its working better on my theme, the other is adding some lines...

Comment: all the `inline-*` will do the same job, the only difference in the inside of the elemen that will be either a block or grid element

Comment: thank you!, not sure how to mark as correct on a comment.

Comment: no need, I already closed as duplicate where you will find the answer there

Comment: thank you, anyway i have solved the issue.